# mongodb mass delete with compound index

Tags: mongodb

Given I have a collection with 1 mio documents of the following form

`{
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: "stuff",
  d: "other"
}`

and there is a compound index on `{a:1, b:1}`

I want to delete 600.000 of those documents and I have [a,b] values for each of the 600.000 that I want to delete.
I found it to be by far faster when deleting them one-by-one than issuing a

`db.collection.remove({$or: [{a:"1", b:"1"}, {a:"3",b:"3"},...]})`

Is that expected? Am I doing something wrong? It feels kind of wrong, that a one-by-one delete is 10x faster than a batch delete that I hand over to the db...

Comment: $or is not going to be efficient here because it will try to run all the queries in parallel where you are running the searches serially. It's a similar reason that $in is better than $or - described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/#_S_or%22   namely: When using indexes with $or queries, remember that each clause of an $or query will execute in parallel.

Comment: is there any sensible approach to the problem then? can i tell $or to search serial?

Comment: so these are arbitrary pairs of a, b values?

Comment: `one-by-one delete is 10x faster than a batch delete`... this is hard to stomach. Are you saying that if 100 individual deletes take 1 minute then the same 100 deletes as a batch are taking 10 minutes?

Comment: when I'm using a $or statement to define the entries to delete, yes. don't take my word for 10x, but at least 3x.

Comment: asya: not really arbitrary, I have a set of 600.000 [a,b] values, that define them. so it's not just "i want to delete 600.000" but "i want to delete exactly those 600.000: `[{a: "foo1", b: "bar1"}, {a: "foo2", b: "bar3"},...]` ... maybe i'm just too stupid to create a sensible query for that. i'm pretty new to plain mongo and its query performance.